# Oracle - Rank by two fields

Tags: oracle, rank

I don't write too many queries. So, it might be a simple question for you. I need to rank a set based on a date in desc order and by a sequence number in asc order. For example:

| ID | Date | Seq | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Jul 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | Jun 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | May 1 | 0 | 5 |

How would I achieve that? The Rank would only allow you to order by multiple fields but by just either asc or desc but not both, right?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query -

```
SELECT ID, "Date", Seq, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE("Date", 'Mon dd') DESC, Seq) Rank
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```